# Ajax success when a view is returned

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm struggling to return a view or partial view with Ajax. Whenever I change the return type to something that isn't JSon the ajax command never succeeds. I need to return a partial view because I want to return a lot of data back.

This is my current code:

(Controller)

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AjaxTestController(string Input)
    {
        string Results = Input + " -- TestTestTest";

        return PartialView("Test", Results);
        //return new JsonResult() { };
    }
```

(View)

```
function AjaxTest() {
alert("test");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Home/AjaxTestController",
    data: "Input=Test11111",        
    success: function () {
        alert("Success!");
    }
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the $.post command for that:

```
function AjaxTest() {
alert("test");
$.post({
    url: "Home/AjaxTestController",
    data: "Input=Test11111",        
    success: function (response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

```
$(function () {
    $('#submit').live('click', function () {
        AjaxTest();
    });
});

function AjaxTest() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("AjaxTestController", "Home")',
        data: { Input: "Test - " + new Date() },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#partialResult').html(data);
        },
        error: function (xhr, err) {
            alert(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
};
```

inside your view and ensure that you have your target div set up for the partial to be populated into:

```
<div id="partialResult"></div>
```

also, for the example above, I added a button to the view to initiate the ajax (purely for testing):

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" />
```

your 'partialview' should look something like this:

```
@model string
<h2>
    Partial Test</h2>
<p>
    @Model
</p>
```

no other changes are required to the existing action for this to now function as required.

**[UPDATE]** - I changed the `AjaxTest()` method to include the error event (the result of which is captured in an alert). hopefully, this may help further.

Comment: I'm a little bit confused... I don't see how that code is going to make the success function trigger when I return a partial view.

Comment: hi there. the 'magic' part is contained here `success: function (data)` where `data` returns the contents of the partialview to your client and then the target div gets populated with that result. i know this works as i actually tried it. what issue are you getting when using the above code?? basically, `success` isn't a function [method] per se, it's an event raised by the `$.ajax` object. it's a big difference really and perhaps this is what's needing clarification in your mind :-)

Comment: Hmm.. assuming that my controller code is correct (in the original post) it still doesn't succeed after making those changes.

Comment: double check your view (i.e. the 'model being passed in. also, check firebug console to see what errors are reported. based on what you've supplied and the rest being 'dreamt up' by my imagination, (i.e. the partialview and the button to trigger the action) the above does actually work. we just need to find where in your view definition an error may be lurking

Comment: I'm pretty sure the view is correct... it's exactly the same. I've followed the code with a break point too, it goes into the controller fine and returns the correct value, the success function just doesn't get called. :(

Comment: do you have a `<div id="partialResult"></div>`
 with the id identified similarly?? this may well be the point of failure. ensure that you have this div in place, as well as targetting that in the success event. keep me posted :)

Comment: Yep, i've done that. I've placed an alert within the success function too and it doesn't get called.

Comment: ok, can you update your question with ALL relevant code as it now stands and i'll pull it into a solution and try it out and then (where required) make the changes that will get it working. also, feel weird asking this, but - does the 'Test' partialview actually exist (either in home or shared)??!! it had to be asked :)

Comment: Nevermind! My problems fixed. Thanks for your help :), the issue was that I hadn't created the partialview. I didn't realise the first string was referring to a cshtml file :P

Comment: ahh - i knew my comment would jog a memory :). if you think it would be helpful, mark this as the answer

Answer (score 0):

partial View is different than view you have to specify the whole path to the partial view or have it in share folder. otherwise is going to return not found and never success.  any way this always work for me, try

```
partialView("~/Views/ControllerView/Test.cshtml")
```